# How do I modify data structures at compile-time in c++?

Tags: c++, c++20, visual-studio-2022, compile-time

First of all, I am new to compile-time code execution (not to C++, I have a few years of experience), so if I say anything stupid please let me know.

I basically want to make the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) algorithm run at compile-time for the first 1000000 numbers (in the code below you can see that I have only the first 1000 numbers, this is because 1000000 numbers would overflow the stack, and the heap is out of the question), and have the program start with an array containing `0` for primes and `1` for the rest. I have tried a few times using a `constexpr` function but I can't get it to work.

This is what I've tried (it's clear it won't work, since `arr` isn't constant):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

constexpr std::array<bool, 1000> Generate()
{
    std::array<bool, 1000> arr{};
    arr[0] = arr[1] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == 0)
            for (int j = 2; i * j < 1000; j++)
                arr[i * j] = true;
    }
    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr std::array<bool, 1000> arr = Generate();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        std::cout << i << ' ' << arr[i] << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Which generates:

> ...\main.cpp(19,41): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant

My questions are:

- How do I modify any data structure at compile-time? (actually, any data at all. examples I've seen simply returned simple things like a sum)
- How do I make it work for 1000000 numbers? Is it even possible?

Also I know I can just precompute the entire thing and just have

```
arr = {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, ...}
```

but my aim is to have the compiler do that, and to use this as proof of concept for compile-time code.

Note: I am using VS2022, and I have set the language standard to c++20

Comment: You may place your array as a global constexpr, which isn't restricted to the stack size.

Comment: There should be more to the error, i.e. which part of the constexpr function wasn't possible to evaluate. I suspect that C++20 accidentally wasn't used, since `T& array<T, N>::operator[]` wasn't constexpr in C++11/14. See your code working here: https://godbolt.org/z/cTvEhEbhP

Answer (score 0):

This will do it (live demo : https://godbolt.org/z/jWM5cMh5f, it shows all the primes end up in data segment, proof they where calculated at compile time)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

// Sieve
template<std::size_t N>
constexpr auto GeneratePrimeLookup()
{
    std::array<bool, N> is_prime{};

    for (auto& p : is_prime) p = true;
 
    for (std::size_t i = 2ul; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (std::size_t j = 2 * i; j < N; j+=i)
        {
            is_prime[j] = false;
        }
    }
    return is_prime;
}


// constexpr to count the number of primes
template<std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t CountPrimes()
{
    auto prime_lookup = GeneratePrimeLookup<N>();
    std::size_t n{ 0ul };
    for (const auto is_prime : prime_lookup)
    {
        if (is_prime) n++;
    }
    return n;
}

// generate an array with only the primes in it.
// with exactly enough room to hold them
template<std::size_t N>
constexpr auto GeneratePrimes()
{
    std::array<std::size_t, CountPrimes<N>()> primes{};
    std::size_t index{ 0ul };
    constexpr std::array<bool,N> prime_lookup = GeneratePrimeLookup<N>();

    for (std::size_t n{ 0ul }; n < N; ++n)
    {
        if (prime_lookup[n])
        {
            primes[index++] = n;
        }
    }

    return primes;
}

// show content
int main()
{
    static constexpr auto primes = GeneratePrimes<100>();

    for (const auto prime : primes)
    {
        std::cout << prime << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did the OP do wrong?

Comment: He only calculated boolean flags (1-1000), the sieve algorithm was not correct (and initialized booleans from ints instead true/false). This will calculate an array only containing the prime numbers

Comment: You should add a `if (!is_prime[i]) continue;` to the outer loop; the multiples of composite numbers should already be filtered out.  https://godbolt.org/z/arGeKnoM5 on 10k elements drops compile time from 6.7s to 4.8s.